# Как лучше сделать данную секцию?

Tags: вёрстка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привет есть такая секция в виде преимуществ. Первый элемент отображается при ховере. Т.е элемент имеет иконку и заголовок а при наведении заголовок меняется и появляется текст, при этом сам блок увеличивается в размерах. Вопрос в том как лучше сделать что бы блок увеличивался плавной + он не выбивался из потока но и другие блоки не сдвигал...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если грубо то

```css
.card-text {
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.4s;
}

.card:hover .card-text {
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
.card  {
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: 0.4s;
    position:absolute!important;
      height: 100px !important;
      width: 200px !important;
}
.card:hover  {
    position:absolute;
      height: 251px !important;
      width: 251px !important;
      z-index: 9;
}
.col-sm-4.py-2 {
    min-height: 115px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="h-100 ">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Danger</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
            <div class="h-100 border-primary">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h3 class="card-title">Primary</h3>
                    <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
            <div class=" ">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h3 class="card-title">Hello</h3>
                     <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                     
                 </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 py-2">
         <div class="card">
             <div class="">
                 <div class="card-body">
                     <h3 class="card-title">Hello</h3>
                     <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                     
                 </div>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```